# Selecting the string in-between the second and third occurrence of a comma

Tags: regex, notepad++

Format:
https://www.urlhere1.com/ , boolean , **str1** , int , str2 ,str3 , float

I would like to find for the first occurrence of the string value.
The value selected should be the first occurrence of **str** with no commas on either side.

> str1

Comment: Try: '(?:[^,]+,){2}([^,]+)' now 'str' will be in group 1.

Comment: Tried this and it ends up highlighting str1 & everything before it.
> 'https://urlhere.com , boolean , str1' was captured.

Comment: @Poul's regex returns the desired text in capture group 1, not the match itself. You could add `(?=,)` (a *positive lookahead*) to the end of Poul's regex if you want it to fail if the string only contains two commas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `((?:[^,]+,){2})([^,]+)` (based on Poul Bak's comment) with a replace value of `$1 replace value` which will allow you to replace the value in str1. $2 will substitute in the value in str1.

On other tools where variable width lookbehind is possible: `(?<=^(?:[^,]+,){2})([^,]+)` will work and do exactly what you want. Although it isn't possible to do so on notepad++.